# Latex Sweave R - page is rotating by itself

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am new to using Sweave with Latex, and am having some small troubles.
Here is the segment of the document put into it's own tex file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{Sweave}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                 END PREAMBLE                                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
data=read.table("adult_dataset/adult.data", sep=",");

age=c(t(data[1]));
fnlwgt=c(t(data[3]));
education_num=c(t(data[5]));
cap_gain=c(t(data[11]));
cap_loss=c(t(data[12]));
hrs_week=c(t(data[13]));

labels=c("Age", "Final weight", "Education num", "Capital gain", "Capital loss", "Hours per week");

dframe=data.frame(age, fnlwgt, education_num, cap_gain, cap_loss, hrs_week);

par(mfrow=c(2,3)); 

for (i in c(1:6) ){
boxplot(dframe[i], main=labels[i]);
}
@
      \label{fig:boxplots}
      \caption{Boxplots of numerical features}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

adult.data is http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data
I compile with:

```
R CMD Sweave test.rnw && latex test.tex && dvipdf test.dvi
```

This produced a page which is horizontal.
It is the correct size, but it is rotated 90 degrees.
Not the picture, but the whole page.

What can I do to fix this?
Is this normal behavior?

Thank you for any suggestions :)

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but may be a ghostscript thing. I get something similar when using bitmap() with "pdfwrite" in R (which uses ghostscript)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dvipdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None test.dvi`